# How do I use variable names in hyperlinks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have tried using the following Python code to create hyperlinks using openpyxl in Python. I tried using variable names but got the error "Reference isn't valid". I also tried using Excel Sheet names with spaces in them which is valid in Excel but the openpyxl hyper link command does not seem to work with them. Finding code examples for openpyxl has been challenging also. Here is the code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

xlsFile = 'e:\\exceltest1.xlsx'
wbook = load_workbook(xlsFile)
Sheet7Name = "Sheet7"
worksheet7 = wbook.create_sheet(title=Sheet7Name)
worksheet9 = wbook.create_sheet(title="Sheet9")
worksheet10 = wbook.create_sheet(title="Sheet 10")
worksheet7.cell(row=3, column=4, value="Go to A1 s9 from D3 s7").hyperlink = '#Sheet9!A1'
worksheet7.cell(row=1, column=1, value="Go to D3 s9 from A1 s7").hyperlink = '#Sheet9!D3'
worksheet7.cell(row=2, column=1, value="Go to A3 s9 from A2 s7").hyperlink = '#Sheet9!A3'
worksheet7.cell(row=4, column=5, value="Go to E6 s7  from E4 s7").hyperlink = '#Sheet7Name!E6'
worksheet7.cell(row=6, column=5, value="Go to E4 s7 from E6 s7").hyperlink = '#Sheet7Name!E4'
worksheet9.cell(row=4, column=1, value="Go to A7 s7 from A4 s9").hyperlink = '#Sheet7Name!A7'
worksheet9.cell(row=3, column=4, value="Go to A1 s9 from D3 s9").hyperlink = '#Sheet9!A1'
worksheet9.cell(row=1, column=1, value="Go to D3 s9 from A1 s9").hyperlink = '#Sheet9!D3'
worksheet9.cell(row=2, column=1, value="Go to A3 s9 from A2 s9").hyperlink = '#Sheet9!A3'
worksheet10.cell(row=2, column=1, value="Go to A3 s10 from A2 s10").hyperlink = '#Sheet 10!A3'
wbook.save(xlsFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this - to link `cell 1` in `Sheet1` to `A1 cell` in `Sheet9`:

```
file_name = "your-excel-file.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(file_name) 
ws1 = wb['Sheet1']

# Create hyperlink to relevant cell
link = file_name+"#Sheet9!A1"

ws1.cell(row=1, column=1).hyperlink = link
ws1.cell(row=1, column=1).value = "Refer to Sheet 9 - Cell A1"
ws1.cell(row=1, column=1).style = "Hyperlink"

wb.save(file_name)
```

And do it for the rest cells you want to hyperlink.

**EDIT:** replaced `wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')` with `ws1 = wb['Sheet1']` because DeprecationWarning.

Comment: When I ran your code I got the following error: "DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_by_name (Use wb[sheetname]).
  ws1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet1")". Is there a way to do it without using a Deprecated function?. Thanks

Comment: Yes there is - instead of `wb.get_sheet_by_name` use `wb['Sheet1']`. Where `Sheet1` is the desired sheet. Sorry about that.

Comment: Tony:Thanks for the quick reply.  I am still getting a "SyntaxEoor: Invalid syntax" with the line ws1 = wb.['Sheet1'].  Here is the full code I am using:from openpyxl import load_workbook
# https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/python-openpyxl-tutorial/


file_name = 'e:\\exceltest1.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(file_name)
ws1 = wb.['Sheet1']

# Create hyperlink to relevant cell
link = file_name+"#Sheet9!A1"

ws1.cell(row=1, column=1).hyperlink = link
ws1.cell(row=1, column=1).value = "Refer to Sheet 9 - Cell A1"
ws1.cell(row=1, column=1).style = "Hyperlink"

wb.save(file_name)

Comment: Just remove the `.` after `wb` it should be like this `ws1=wb['Sheet1']`

Comment: Here is the code I am using.  When I click on cell A1 , it gives the error: "Cannot open the specified file".  Can you successfully run the same code? from openpyxl import load_workbook
# https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/python-openpyxl-tutorial/


file_name = 'e:\\exceltest1.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(file_name)
ws1 = wb['Sheet1']

# Create hyperlink to relevant cell
link = file_name+"#Sheet1!A9"

ws1.cell(row=1, column=1).hyperlink = link
ws1.cell(row=1, column=1).value = "Refer to Sheet 1 - Cell A9"
ws1.cell(row=1, column=1).style = "Hyperlink"

wb.save(file_name)

Comment: Yes I did run it but my `xslx` file is in the same directory where the `.py` is. And because of that I don't need to set the whole path. The error is exaclty that - try it the way I described. I think your path, if you choose to use it, should be `file_name = : "E:/exceltest1.xlsx"`. The import is also not correct `from openpyxl import Workbook`